# Deleting string of a string to its end in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, replace, contains

if i have this:

```
Dim str as String = "This is a string to delete"
```

i used the contain method to detect the "String" inside the `str` if found the "String" will be deleted also the next character to the last character of the str.

```
str = "This is a "
```

Comment: Please try to clarify the question or specify what the expected output should be.

Comment: There is no question here, but I think the term you want is `SubString()`

Comment: @Plutonix yes i found it here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y7ddk24.aspx

Comment: what are you asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to remove the last part of the string is to use `IndexOf` to find the location of the part you want to delete, and `Substring` to delete it

```
Dim str As String = "This is a string to delete"
Dim loc As Integer = str.IndexOf("string")
If loc >= 0 Then str = str.Substring(0, loc)
```

Comment: im going to accept this because its the same of the code i write :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are wanting to remove a specified string, plus the first character that follows that string.  If that is correct, it can be done like this:

```
Dim str As String = "This is a string to delete"
Dim stringToRemove As String = "string"
str = str.Replace(str.Substring(InStr(str, stringToRemove) - 1, stringToRemove.Length + 1), "")
```